# MySQL SELECT multiple rows in one table, SUM on different table with WHERE statement

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm trying to figure out how create a MySQL `SELECT` statement that will select users from one table, get the `SUM` of their payments in another table for each user, and set a conditional statement on that `SUM`. Something like this:

```
SELECT member_id
FROM users_table
WHERE SUM(payments) FROM payments_table > 100;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

something like

```
select member_id from payments_table 
group by member_id 
having sum(payments) > 100
```

or

```
select u.member_id, u.name 
from payments_table p 
join users_table u
on p.member_id = u.member_id
group by u.member_id, u.name 
having sum(p.payments) > 100
```

Comment: i guess this query will work fine because member_id is a foreign key in the payment table .. is that the case ?